# PortfolioAnalytics: What is the training_period and rolling_window "type" in optimize.portfolio.rebalancing?

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, rebalancing

In R-package PortfolioAnalytics, what is the unit of the `training_period` and `rolling_window` ? is it the just data points ? or is it related to the `rebalance_on` period?

Edit/precisions: example: if I put `training_period = 50` what is the unit of that `50`? Turns out, it's `50` time periods, the same as the returns series.

Comment: All of the params are defined quite clearly here on pages 83-85: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/PortfolioAnalytics.pdf  There is some example code in that link as well demonstrating one way to implement it.

Comment: Please quote. I have the pdf.

Comment: training_period: an integer of the number of periods to use as a training data in the front of the returns data
rolling_window: an integer of the width (i.e. number of periods) of the rolling window, the default of NULL will run the optimization using the data from inception.

Comment: My question is: what is the period? Is it related to rebalance on? Do they subsample? If I use daily returns, are the periods in days? If monthly, is it months?

Comment: Your question was the "type" or "unit" to which the answer is integer... Anyway, the period depends on what data you have...days, months, quarters, years, etc.  Yes, it is all related.  Yes, there is subsampling unless you just want to do a single in-sample backward looking optimization--which will not be useful.  It seems that your question is quite a bit more in depth than your OP...You should edit.

Comment: Hi @amdopt, you are right. If the returns are daily, then the `training_period` and `rolling_window` are in daily "units". It is not dependent on the `rebalance_on` parameter. I'm going to edit. If you want to add the answer below so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On pages 83-85 in the link below:

> training_period: an integer of the number of periods to use as a
>   training data in the front of the returns.
>
> data rolling_window: an integer of the width (i.e., number of periods)
>   of the rolling window, the default of NULL will run the optimization
>   using the data from inception.

So the "type" is integer.  The "unit" depends on what data you have...minutes, hours, days, months, quarters, years, etc. That period is the "unit" you are asking about which will also be of "type" integer and will be the same unit as your time series.  The other input you ask about, "rebalance_on," is a string input ("Months," "Quarters," etc.).  Below is taken directly from page 85 in the link below as well.  The code snippet would optimize for ROI via monthly rebalancing with five year training period and 4-year rolling window.

```
bt.opt2 <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R, portf,
optimize_method="ROI",
rebalance_on="months",
training_period=60,
rolling_window=48)
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/PortfolioAnalytics.pdf